# creating a proper array summary

Tags: php, arrays

I am working on a script to create a summary of items.  The only thing that doesn't appear to be working correctly is the item summary amounts.  That is to say that these three lines display the last value for the price instead of a sum:

```
echo "<td><strong>" . number_format($summary['counterExtended'], 2) . "</strong></td>";
echo "<td><strong>" . number_format($summary['onlineExtended'],  2) . "</strong></td>";
echo "<td><strong>" . number_format($summary['voucherExtended'], 2) . "</strong></td>";
```

Even though I have them being added here:

```
if (true === isset($lineItems[$category][$description])) {

    $data                    = $lineItems[$category][$description];
    $data['quantity']        += $qty;
    $data['counterExtended'] += $counterExtended;
    $data['onlineExtended']  += $onlineExtended;
    $data['voucherExtended'] += $voucherExtended;

    $lineItems[$category][$description] = $data;

    $categoryTotals[$category]['counterExtended'] += $counterExtended;
    $categoryTotals[$category]['onlineExtended']  += $onlineExtended;
    $categoryTotals[$category]['voucherExtended'] += $voucherExtended;
```

I'll note that QTY adds up just fine, just not $counterExtended, $onlineExtended, $voucherExtended.  They only display the last value instead of adding up all the values for each item, per month.

Here is the SQL loop:

```
$s->bind_result($id, $qty, $price, $online, $voucher, $month, $year, $description, $cat, $category);

    $lineItems      = array();
    $categoryTotals = array();

    while($s->fetch()) {

            if ($online == 0 && $voucher == 0) {
                $counterExtended = $qty * $price;
                $onlineExtended  = 0;
                $voucherExtended = 0;
            }

            if ($online == 1) {
                $counterExtended = 0;
                $onlineExtended  = $qty * $price;
                $voucherExtended = 0;
            }

            if ($voucher == 1) {
                $counterExtended = 0;
                $onlineExtended  = 0;
                $voucherExtended = $qty * $price;
            }

        // Repeated item, increment values accordingly
        if (true === isset($lineItems[$category][$description])) {

            $data                    = $lineItems[$category][$description];
            $data['quantity']        += $qty;
            $data['counterExtended'] += $counterExtended;
            $data['onlineExtended']  += $onlineExtended;
            $data['voucherExtended'] += $voucherExtended;

            $lineItems[$category][$description] = $data;

            $categoryTotals[$category]['counterExtended'] += $counterExtended;
            $categoryTotals[$category]['onlineExtended']  += $onlineExtended;
            $categoryTotals[$category]['voucherExtended'] += $voucherExtended;

        // First time hitting an item with this description
        } else {

            $lineItems[$category][$description] = array(
                'category'        => $category,
                'description'     => $description,
                'id'              => $id,
                'counterExtended' => $counterExtended,
                'onlineExtended'  => $onlineExtended,
                'voucherExtended' => $voucherExtended,
                'quantity'        => $qty,
                'year'            => $year,
            );

            $categoryTotals[$category] = array(
                'counterExtended' => $counterExtended,
                'onlineExtended'  => $onlineExtended,
                'voucherExtended' => $voucherExtended,
            );
        }

    }

    // Now loop through the $lineItems array and output rows.
    foreach ($categoryTotals as $category => $summary) {

        while ($item = array_shift($lineItems[$category])) {
            echo "<tr>";
            echo '<td>'.$item['year'].'</td>';
            echo '<td>'.$item['id'].'</td>';
            echo '<td>'.$item['quantity'].'</td>';
            echo "<td></td>";
            echo "<td>" . number_format($item['counterExtended'],2) . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . number_format($item['onlineExtended'],2) . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . number_format($item['voucherExtended'],2) . "</td>";
            echo '<td>'.$item['description'].'</td>';
            echo '<td>'.$item['category'].'</td>';
            echo "</tr>\n";
        }

        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td colspan=4></td>";
        echo "<td><strong>" . number_format($summary['counterExtended'], 2) . "</strong></td>";
        echo "<td><strong>" . number_format($summary['onlineExtended'],  2) . "</strong></td>";
        echo "<td><strong>" . number_format($summary['voucherExtended'], 2) . "</strong></td>";
        echo "<td><strong>$category</strong>";
        echo "<td></td>";
        echo "</tr>";

    }


        $counterGrand=$counterGrand+$counterCat;
        $onlineGrand=$onlineGrand+$onlineCat;
        $voucherGrand=$voucherGrand+$voucherCat;
```

Comment: Just offhand, it looks like you're adding to `$data`, not `$summary`.

Comment: @Don'tPanic He's doing both. He adds to `$summary` in `$categoryTotals[$category]['counterExtended'] += $counterExtended;`

Comment: I think the problem may be that you re-initialize `$categoryTotals[$category]` whenever `$lineItems[$category][$description]` is not set. So whenever you get a new description, you reset the totals for the whole category.

Comment: Sorry about that; should have looked all the way through before commenting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every time you encounter a new `$description` in an existing `$category`, you reinitialize `$categoryTotals[$category]` from the current row, which wipes out the running total for that category. You should only initialize this entry when you see the category for the first time.

```
while ($s->fetch()) {
    if (!isset($categoryTotals[$category])) {
        $categoryTotals[$category] = array('counterExtended' => 0, 'onlineExtended' => 0, 'voucherExtended' => 0);
        $lineItems[$category] = array();
    }
    if (!isset($lineItems[$category][$description])) {
        $lineItems[$category][$description] = array('quantity' => 0, 'counterExtended' => 0, 'onlineExtended' => 0, 'voucherExtended' => 0);
    }
    $data                    =& $lineItems[$category][$description]; // Use reference so we don't make a copy that we have to assign back
    $data['quantity']        += $qty;
    $data['counterExtended'] += $counterExtended;
    $data['onlineExtended']  += $onlineExtended;
    $data['voucherExtended'] += $voucherExtended;

    $categoryTotals[$category]['counterExtended'] += $counterExtended;
    $categoryTotals[$category]['onlineExtended']  += $onlineExtended;
    $categoryTotals[$category]['voucherExtended'] += $voucherExtended;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Barmar.  I had to make some changes, here is my final code:

```
   while($s->fetch()) {

            if ($online == 0 && $voucher == 0) {
                $counterExtended = $qty * $price;
                $onlineExtended  = 0;
                $voucherExtended = 0;
            }

            if ($online == 1) {
                $counterExtended = 0;
                $onlineExtended  = $qty * $price;
                $voucherExtended = 0;
            }

            if ($voucher == 1) {
                $counterExtended = 0;
                $onlineExtended  = 0;
                $voucherExtended = $qty * $price;
            }

        // Repeated item, increment values accordingly

    if (!isset($categoryTotals[$category])) {
        $categoryTotals[$category] = array('counterExtended' => 0, 'onlineExtended' => 0, 'voucherExtended' => 0);
        $lineItems[$category] = array();
    }
    if (!isset($lineItems[$category][$description])) {
        $lineItems[$category][$description] = array('quantity' => 0, 'counterExtended' => 0, 'onlineExtended' => 0, 'voucherExtended' => 0);
    }
    $data                    =& $lineItems[$category][$description]; // Use reference so we don't make a copy that we have to assign back
    $data['quantity']        += $qty;
    $data['counterExtended'] += $counterExtended;
    $data['onlineExtended']  += $onlineExtended;
    $data['voucherExtended'] += $voucherExtended;
    $data['description']     = $description;
    $data['year']            = $year;
    $data['id']              = $id;



    $categoryTotals[$category]['counterExtended'] += $counterExtended;
    $categoryTotals[$category]['onlineExtended']  += $onlineExtended;
    $categoryTotals[$category]['voucherExtended'] += $voucherExtended;


        // First time hitting an item with this description


    }

    // Now loop through the $lineItems array and output rows.
    foreach ($categoryTotals as $category => $summary) {

        while ($item = array_shift($lineItems[$category])) {
            echo "<tr>";
            echo '<td>'.$item['year'].'</td>';
            echo '<td>'.$item['id'].'</td>';
            echo '<td>'.$item['quantity'].'</td>';
            echo "<td></td>";
            echo "<td>" . number_format($item['counterExtended'],2) . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . number_format($item['onlineExtended'],2) . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . number_format($item['voucherExtended'],2) . "</td>";
            echo '<td>'.$item['description'].'</td>';
            echo '<td>'.$item['category'].'</td>';
            echo "</tr>\n";
        }

        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td colspan=4></td>";
        echo "<td><strong>" . number_format($summary['counterExtended'], 2) . "</strong></td>";
        echo "<td><strong>" . number_format($summary['onlineExtended'],  2) . "</strong></td>";
        echo "<td><strong>" . number_format($summary['voucherExtended'], 2) . "</strong></td>";
        echo "<td><strong>$category</strong>";
        echo "<td></td>";
        echo "</tr>";

        $counterGrand+=$summary['counterExtended'];
        $onlineGrand+=$summary['onlineExtended'];
        $voucherGrand+=$summary['voucherExtended'];

    }
```